# Синтаксический анализ. Вычисление выражения.

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

- X = 5
- Y = X + 5
- Как сделать так чтобы получилось Y =
     10?

Comment: Шутка с долей правды: скормить эти строки (выражения ведь в разных строках?) программе runghc (runhaskell) или им подобным. Они сосчитают :) Правда к этому тексту придётся добавить выражения, которые передадут вам нужные значения в нужном вам виде. Правда в haskell имена переменных должны начинаться со строчной буквы.

Comment: @marioxxx проверка повторности? использовать словарь (например map из STL). Если значение уже существует, новое не заносить.

Comment: В массиве поиск надо реализовывать. Линейный -- o(n^2) по сложности, а в map вроде бинарные деревья (если не путаю). И значения переменных  в качестве значений в парах.

Comment: Поиск -- `map::find`, или при включении получите пару: итератор (на новый или старый элемент с этим ключом) и bool -- истина, если новый элемент вставлен.

Comment: **Опять текст вопрос исчез**, а ответы остались. 

@marioxxx, если Вы это делаете (так правите свой вопрос), то советую сменить ник и больше так **никогда** не поступать.

Comment: т.е. я ни имею право так делать? 
я об этом не знал...
впредь так не буду делать

Comment: @marioxx Править свой вопрос можно, но так чтобы текст на котором **уже базируются ответы** не исчезал и не искажался. Иначе смысл ответов-комментариев необъяснимо искажается. 

IMHO лучше делать правки, отмечаемые какой-то выделенной фразой **UPDATE-xxx**, что ли ?

Вот прямо сейчас прочтите свой вопрос и **все** ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать таблицу символов ИМЯ:Значение с возможностью изменения значений.

При синтаксическом анализе своих выражений в правой части вместо имени подставляйте его текущее значение. После вычисления выражения меняйте в таблице значение для Имени из левой части присваивания.

На самом деле вычисление правой части можно совместить с анализом.

Comment: Ежели с вычислением не спешить, то порядок формул будет уже не важен. Ну а для удаления лишних вычислений -- мемоизация.

Comment: @marioxxx, я Вам ответил (еще 9 января). Вы продлжаете задавать **тот же вопрос** немного меняя его. 

Опишите (*русскими* словами, по шагам) Ваш алгоритм (и структуры данных). 

Что именно вызывает затруднения ?

Comment: Да я по другому сделал... без двух выражений, а только с одним выражением. Т.е. вычисление выражения 
Y = 5 + 5 -> 
Y = 10.
Спасибо за ответы, особенно вам avp! Уважение поставил бы, но я в минусах=)

Comment: @marioxxx, вам следует принять ответ, если он верный. Для этого вам не нужно иметь репутацию выше определенного значения.

Comment: Angry Bird мне следует принять? оо какие директивы) Извините, но я вас не понял.

Comment: Рядом с ответом есть иконки "палец вверх", "палец вниз" и "галка". Приннять - это нажать на галку. Она потом зелененькой станет.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не совсем понятно задан.

> Когда перебираю строку у меня хранится
> в одномерном массиме строк, а когда
> перебираю 2-ю строку тот же массив
> использую.

Но если я правильно понял и Вам нужно написать простенький синтаксический анализатор, то можно подсмотреть в книге [Шилдт - полный справочник по C](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/966202/). Там приведен небольшой готовый пример с объяснениями. На сайте издательства можно скачать [код](http://www.mhprofessional.com/downloads/products/0072121246/0072121246_code.zip).